# Move to a div element on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have full height divs for my web page. What I want to do is move to the next div if I am scrolling.

```
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="services"></div>
```

So when I scroll on home, it should go directly to Services. I am not sure if scroll() of jQuery will help?

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at some jQuery plugins for this:

- http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html